# mount through fuseiso9660 appending ;1 to filenames

Tags: debian, non-root-user, iso, fuse

I want to mount iso9660 files without root permissions through some program and I have chosen `fuseiso9660` for this purpose.

But whenever I use the command
`fuseiso9660 /path/to/iso /mountpoint/under/home`
I can see the files under mount point, but all the filenames are appended with `;1` , and all the filenames and folder names are capitalized.

This breaks things. Actually the iso file contains html files that are linked to each other. And when filename is changed, the redirects no longer work.

I have also tried `Archive Mounter` program. It does mount iso files but the file path starts with `archive:/` which is not recognized by browser to process html files.

So, how can I properly mount iso to some absolute user path without root permissions ?

Comment: Did you create the iso file? You are only seeing the basic filenames. To have the long filenames you need to have an iso created with RockRidge or Joliet extensions.

Comment: I created the iso with brasero. I also tried standard iso9660 file (debian netinst iso). All the iso's have the same file name issue.

Comment: fuseiso9660 is showing the image in basic ISO9660 format, which only supports uppercase file names, limited to 11 characters in a 8.3 format (almost, but not entirely like MS-DOS), and with a version number separated from the main part of the name by a semicolon. Normally it should use extensions to this basic format if present: Joliet which allows longer and mixed-case names, and RockRidge which supports longer and case-sensitive names and Unix-like permissions. What distribution are you using? What does `file /path/to/iso` say?

Comment: The iso's when loop mounted are fine. I'm using debian jessie 8.2 up-to-date packages. fuseiso9660 version is 0.3-1.1 . The file iso command gives `filename.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'iso label'`. For debian iso, it gives `debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Debian 8.2.0 amd64 1' (bootable); partition 2 : ID=0xef, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 20224, 832 sectors` . I think the iso files use RockRidge/Joliet extensions, if so, How can I use them with fuseiso9660?